# gem5-ARM-Fullsystem faild

Tags: gem5

I sued ubuntu 18.04 with gcc 7.04 and python 2,7,15 and protobuf 3 and swig 3,0,12.when I run ARM-fullsystem, I have problem:

```
my setting for fullsytem is:
```

1. sudo su

```
2. mkdir fullsystem
```

3. cd fullsystem
4. wget http://www.gem5.org/dist/current/arm/arm-system-2011-08.tar.bz2
5. echo export M5_PATH=/home/farideh/gem5/fullsystem/>> ~/.bashrc

   6. gedit ~/.bashrc
6. echo $M5_PATH
7. source ~/.bashrc

   9. configs/common/SysPaths.py , path = [ '/dist/m5/system', '/home/farideh/gem5/fullsystem' ]
8. configs/common/Benchmarks.py ,

   elif buildEnv['TARGET_ISA'] == 'arm':

   return env.get('LINUX_IMAGE', disk('linaro-minimal-aarch64.img'))

//////////////////////////////////////////

```
then running this command:
```

warn: Kernel panic in simulated kernel
/////////////////////////

I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: Which kind of command you try to run? "warn: Kernel panic in simulated kernel" is just an error, not a command.

Comment: ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py --cpu="minor" \
   --num-cores=1 --disk-image=$M5_PATH/disks/linaro-minimal-aarch64.img --kernel=/home/farideh/gem5/fullsystem/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1.20170616